# How do I use ExternalProject_Add to get a simple make invocation?

Tags: cmake

I need ExternalProject_Add to invoke just one command for an external project whose makefile does all the needed steps. I need to have that command be "make WITH_OPTION1=no WITH_OPTION2=no" in the directory at the top of the external project's source tree. This is one of a few dozen external projects we use. Most of them fit the model of 'configure; make; make install' but a good third don't and this is one that I thought would be easy.

If I try to have the make command invoked like this:

```
   ExternalProject_Add(build-example
        PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/example"
        DEPENDS ""
        SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_TOPDIR}/External/example"
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_COMMAND COMMAND make WITH_OPTION1=no WITH_OPTION2=no
        INSTALL_COMMAND "")
```

The resulting make step is done from the wrong directory and therefore the Makefile is not found.

If I add a -C option to the make command it seems to use the right directory, but it ignores the WITH_OPTION stuff. That doesn't compile properly, because those features use things I don't want to provide, and if it did work, I still don't want those features.

If I then add quotes around the entire desired make command, it goes wrong. Apparently the command is passed to 'sh' in such a way that sh fails.

If I use a mechanism to pass the command into a 'configure-file' step and invoke that file from the BUILD_COMMAND, then CMake actually tries to use a broken CMakeLists.txt file that's in the external project, and I wonder what makes CMake think that it should do so.

I just want to invoke the makefile properly, using CMake to organize that build within the dozens of other builds that have to be done to build the complete project.

Comment: Generally, `ExternalProject_Add` distinguish **source directory**, where the sources resides, and **build directory**, where build artifacts are created. Exactly *build directory* is used for call the `COMMAND`s. It seems your project doesn't need separate build directory and its artifacts are created near the sources. In that case, just pass `BUILD_IN_SOURCE` option for `ExternalProject_Add` command.

Comment: Also, after `BUILD_COMMAND` keyword the common `COMMAND` keyword is not needed.

Comment: I tried the BUILD_IN_SOURCE option and removing the redundant COMMAND in the BUILD_COMMAND. The right directory is now used but the make is invoked without the desired options.

Comment: `BUILD_COMMAND make WITH_OPTION1=no WITH_OPTION2=no` should correctly call `make WITH_OPTION1=no WITH_OPTION2=no`. BTW, when build the main project via `make`, pass `VERBOSE=1` option to it and check exact command lines which are run.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I had a misspelling that was also frustrating my efforts. Also this Makefile I'm using doesn't make its library using 'normal' naming conventions, and finally, I need to get the cross-compiler involved so I may have to use a layer of indirection, as I alluded to in my question. I don't know if it is necessary, but if you like, you may put your comments in the form of an answer and I'll accept. I have work to do still but your help has been valuable.